# JavaScript - If statement in if statement condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, logic

I want to check for an element's existence in the if statement condition, and if so then use the element as part of the comparison. Something like this:

```
if( if($(".element").length > 0) { $.contains( $(".element")[0], $("[ele]")[0] )} ) {...
```

I know I could just nest if statements, like:

```
if($(".element").length > 0) {
    if($.contains( $(".element")[0], $("[ele]")[0] )) {....
```

But is there a shorter way to do this? Can if statements be used in another if statement's condition like this in some way?

Comment: use `&&`, as intended

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the [boolean AND operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_())…

Comment: Not sure about `$("[ele]")`, but why not just `if ( $('.element [ele]').length  )` -> https://jsfiddle.net/t6bvobvm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `&&` operator to chain both of your conditions:

```
if($(".element").length > 0 && $.contains( $(".element")[0], $("[ele]")[0] )) {
```

If the the first condition fails (code prior to `&&`), it will short out and not execute the second condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `&&` (and) operator for that.  If the thing on the left side of the `&&` is false, then it doesn't evaluate the right side of `&&`, so you don't have to worry about any errors from the element not existing.  (This is called short-circuit evaluation, and `||` (or) does a similar thing, except `||` doesn't evaluate the right side if the left side it true.)  So

```
if($(".element").length > 0 && $.contains( $(".element")[0], $("[ele]")[0] )) ...
```

It's not necessary here, but if you want an `if`-`else` inside an expression, you can use the `?:` (ternary conditional) operator.  `condition ? a : b` is like `if(condition) a else b`, except it's actually an expression, so for instance, `x = (condition ? a : b)` is the same as `if(condition) x = a; else x = b;`.